# A single thread on CUDA

Tags: cuda

I am invoking a CUDA kernel with only one block and only one thread inside this block, e.g.

kernel<<<1, 1>>>

Will this kernel be executed only on a *single* CUDA core as specified? 
So for instance if the GPU has 128 cores, only 1 of the 128 will be working?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. CUDA is an SIMD style architecture and the basic execution unit is a *warp* -- a grouping of 32 threads which are executed lock step wise on the hardware. If you launch a single block containing a single thread, the hardware will be executing a single warp of 32 threads, 31 of which are masked out and execute the equivalent of a stream of noops. Any given warp is executed on a single streaming multiprocessor, and depending on the generation of hardware you are using, that might involve 8, 16 or 32 cores of the SM on which it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Each CUDA core is a lane in SM's SIMD. Your kernel activates only one SM and utilizes one of the lanes. So the kernel<<<1,1>>> is very inefficient, utilizing only one lane of one SM.