# Are blocks of only one thread efficient?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Assuming there are no inter-thread communications and no other processes on the GPU,

which is faster, launching `N` blocks of `1` thread, or `N/32` blocks of `32 (warp size)` threads? when `N <= 32` and `32 < N < 32 * number_of_SMs` respectively?

---

I'm assuming block size of 32 is optimal in terms of latency when N is small enough, since a warp will be executed in parallel by the same SM. Please let me know if there are better block sizes.

Comment: To quote the [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multiprocessor-level): "The number of threads per block should be chosen as a multiple of the warp size to avoid wasting computing resources with under-populated warps as much as possible." Also, the chapter on [Compute Capabilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) lists limits on the number of blocks per SM. You will limit your occupancy with just 32 threads per block

Comment: The Best Practices Guide also outlines [guidelines on this topic](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#thread-and-block-heuristics)

Comment: Memory access/coalescing is another reason to use bigger blocks (in most cases 128 or 256 threads). By using so few threads per block, you are wasting time putting data into L1 caches that is then not used at all and which will probably be loaded again from another SM.

Comment: I think generally in parallel processing with limited parallelism, you should prioritize the lowest/lightest/cheapest level of parallelism (SIMD/Pipelining/Warp/Block), not the highest/heaviest/most expensive (Distributed/Multi-GPU/Multi-SM)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A single thread on CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795483/a-single-thread-on-cuda)

Answer (score 2):

> Are blocks of only one thread efficient?

No, almost by definition. GPUs are processors focused on parallel execution, particularly within the single physical core (which executes complete blocks of threads). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13795657/1593077).

> which is faster, launching N blocks of 1 thread, or N/32 blocks of 32 (warp size) threads?

N/32 blocks of 32 threads - for reasonable N; but in your case...

> when N <= 32

If your problem size is so small, the question becomes practically irrelevant. "Don't sweat the small stuff": Profile your app and see what actually takes the bulk of time.

Now, if you've partitioned your problem into N units of independent work which take a huge amount of time each - with no communication among the threads doing that work - your partition of the problem is inefficient. Let more threads work on what is now a single thread's work.

> 32 < N < 32 * number_of_SMs

Still too small, same point as before.

> I'm assuming block size of 32 is optimal

It usually isn't.

> Please let me know if there are better block sizes.

It depends on the specifics of your kernel. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483876/1593077). And while you can often estimate what a good choice of block dimensions might be - you usually also need to empirically check, if only to verify your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Block of one thread is the most inefficient choice!
The beginning is to use 32 threads.
I usually have a test phase at the start of my simulations where I test different grid configurations, typically 32,64,128,256,512,1024 threads to find the most efficient configuration. Bearing in mind that depending on the computational load/memory pressure, the best choice may change.